# Java print contents of an array

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I have a constructor  that accepts an array length as a parameter and fills the array with random numbers using another method.

```
public class RandomArray {

public RandomArray(int length) {
    array = new int[length];
    for (int index = 0; index <= array.length; index++) {
         array[index] = randomFill();
        }
    }

public int randomFill()
    {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(length);
    return num;
    }

}
```

It compiles but am not sure how to print the values in the array using the constructor? This is what I have tried

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayGenerator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    RandomArray array = new RandomArray(5);
    for (int index = array.length -1; index >= 0; index++)
        System.out.println(array[index]);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that you never store the array in the RandomArray class. Try doing something like this:

```
public class RandomArray {
int myArray [];

public RandomArray(int length) {
    myArray = new int[length];
    for (int index = 0; index <= array.length; index++) {
         myArray[index] = randomFill();
        }
    }

public int randomFill()
    {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(length);
    return num;
    }

public int [] getArray(){
    return this.myArray;
 }
}
```

Then in your main method you can get this array by calling the `getArray` method and iterating through it. This is not at all the best way to do this, but this is how within your framework it will work.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comment and other answer, your for loop in the main method needs to be fixed and iterate from 0 through array.length, and not as you have it set now.

Comment: I think the test condition should be `index < array.length` in the for loop since it is a   zero based count.

Comment: Yeah I didn't read through the iteration of the loop - i'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code snippet.There are several options to print the contents.Since you have said that you need to print array contents within the constructors i have inserted a print statement within the same while loop as the assignment of numbers. if you want you can have two separate loops. One each for number assignment and number printing.

```
public class RandomArray {
int newArr[];

public RandomArray(int size) {
    newArr= new int[size];
    int counter=0;
    while(newArr.size()>counter){
       newArr[counter] = randomFill();
       System.out.println(newArr[counter]);
       counter++;
    }

    }

public int randomFill()
    {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(length);
    return num;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, as Sun noted, you will need to declare an array. After that, however, you can use the for loop you have to print each element.

However, you will want to change the conditions of the loop slightly

```
for(int index = array.length - 1; **index >= 0**; index++)
```

is incorrect, as the loop will continue iterating since you continually add to index and have no upper limit set to stop at. I suggest you change that line to read

```
for(int index = 0; index <= array.length; index++)
```

Comment: The OP might want to print the array backwards, so `index--` would work.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Initially reading his post, I thought he just meant a standard ++ iteration